# Total de Subregistros - MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Em meu banco de tenho várias tabelas, mas vou fazer um exemplo simples do que quero fazer:

Supondo duas tabelas:

- Tabela 1

> id | loja | data

- Tabela 2

> id_2 | id_tab1_2 | produto

Percebam que o `id_tab1_2` é uma chave estrangeira, ligado ao campo `id` da tabela 1.

O que eu quero é **EM UMA ÚNICA QUERY** trazer todos os registros da **Tabela 1** e a quantidade de sub registros da **Tabela 2**, ex:

`SELECT * FROM tabela_1 ...`

E o resultado fosse algo parecido com isso:

id | loja |   data     | quant_tab_2

1  |   X  | 23/07/2018 |      2

2  |   Y  | 23/07/2018 |      1

3  |   Z  | 23/07/2018 |      0

No campo **quant_tab_2** vem a quantidade se sub registros na **Tabela 2** de cada registro da **Tabela 1**

Não que tenha que vir uma coluna com o nome **quant_tab_2**, é só um exemplo, eu não quero ter que fazer pra cada registro da **Tabela 1**, uma nova query pra saber quantos sub registros dela há na **Tabela 2**, é possível fazer isso? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com base na sua suposição, a `query` ficaria dessa forma:

```
SELECT
tabela_1.id,
tabela_1.loja,
tabela_1.data,
COUNT(tabela_2.id_2) as quant_tab_2
FROM tabela_1
LEFT JOIN tabela_2 ON (tabela_1.id = tabela_2.id_tab1_2)
GROUP BY tabela_1.id
```

Comment: É isso msm, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo do tipo:

select t1.*, count(t2.produto) from tabela1 as t1

inner join tabela2  as t2 on t2.id_tab1_2 = t1.id

group by t2.id_tab1_2